# Can python's importlib work in concurrent environment?

Tags: python, django, concurrency

I have a question. I'm using importlib in Django to dynamic load a specific module at runtime, and then using the imported module to work around. Using this way can reduce much code in my project. But I'm not sure whether it is suitable for concurrent environment. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: What do you mean by "using the imported module to work around"?

Answer (score 0):

If by concurrent environment, you mean separate processes, then it should be perfectly fine. If you are sharing imported modules among threads of same application, it should still be fine, as long as they are python threads and the modules imported are pure-python. For what it's worth, I hope you are not using sub-interpreters for concurrency. I am not sure of behavior for imported modules among sub-interpreters.